# Windows 10 search nonfunctional since June updates

Tags: windows-10, search

Since the June 2023 patches, my Windows 10 search has not been working. At first the query "thinks" for several seconds indicated by the top of the popup window rolling through the little dots animation, then it just disappears, as well as the actual textbox contained in the task bar disappearing briefly. This is very disruptive as search has become the shortcut to starting up many nested programs and settings

Windows 10 Pro 21H2 Build 19044.3086

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 Pro Search is working fine on two Windows 10 machines here.

1. You are not up to date.  Windows 10 current 22H2 19045 3208.  So for sure update Windows 10.
2. Run DISM / SFC:

> (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
>
> (2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
>
> (3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
>
> (4) SFC /SCANNOW
>
> (5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

3. Hopefully Update and DISM will fix Search. If not, post back. The next step is a Windows 10 Repair Install from the Microsoft Media Creation Link.

> Windows 10/11 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade
> Button) and select Run. This will launch the Repair.  Proceed normally
> answering the prompts. The default Keep prompt is to Keep Everything.

If updates on your system are not working, a Repair Install will also bring it up to date.

[image: Windows 10 Current Version]

Comment: This is a lie, I am fully up to date on Windows 10. There is no higher build

Comment: 21h2 is almost a year old.  That is what you posted.  22H2 is current.  Also try DISM and SFC.  The current version I posted is correct

Comment: There are zero updates available to this Windows 10. It has the June patches and July just happened yesterday. 22H2 is a Windows 11 build

Comment: Something is wrong with your OS, so now try the Repair Install step to bring your system up to date and begin updating again.  I added the necessity to repair Windows to start it updating again

Comment: Please be careful about your language (This is a lie)  as what I posted is very true

Comment: I posted a screen shot of up to date Windows 10